# Does Alibaba Cloud can support Cloud Devops story?

Tags: cloud, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs, alibaba-cloud-function-compute, alibaba-cloud-direct-mail

Does Alibaba Cloud supports the a complete devops story ? I'm looking to similar one IBM Blue Mix story on the principles of Think,Learn, Build, Deploy and Run where all tasks were automated. Code executed in Delivery pipe lines as stages and move to Build and Deploy , Test cases made easy ? if not available do you know by when we can see this features added to Alibaba Cloud ?

Thanks,
Srinivas B

Answer (score 3):

DevOps is not "A" tool, but a concept to automate development and operation process. For Alibaba Cloud, you have tool called ROS to orchestrate resources, in addition, terraform is supported, and you have full SDK support for API calls.
In this view, Alibaba Cloud has already good support on DevOps.

However, comparing to Alibaba Cloud in China or AWS, many key functionalities not yet supported overseas (git repo, pipeline, code check...)

But overall, it provides definitely more than PaaS based on Cloud Foundry.

Answer (score 0):

For now, we should see Alibaba Cloud provides Infrastructure as a Service(IaaS) & Software as a service(SaaS). IBM Bluemix is their proprietary product. As per my knowledge, I don't see anything like that in near future.

IMHO you can build one using the GitLab pipelines that might not be similar to IBM Bluemix but for some extent.

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix is an implementation of IBM's Open Cloud Architecture, based on Cloud Foundry, that enables you to rapidly create, deploy, and manage your cloud applications.IBM Bluemix is a PAAS (Platform as a Service).

Serverless Computing aims to allow applications to be developed without concerns for implementing, tweaking, or scaling a server (Complete DevOps Story)

**FaaS** provides a means to achieve the **serverless** dream allowing developers to execute code in response to events without building out or maintaining a complex infrastructure.

**Alibaba Cloud** provides IaaS, PaaS and **FaaS** ( It is more similar to the one you are expecting )

Answer (score 0):

DevOps is a Software engineering culture and practice that aims at unifying software development(Dev) and software operation(Ops).Alibaba Cloud Support Devops and
various automated tools used in DevOps On Alibaba Cloud are

- For build Automation
  -Java-ant,maven,gradle
  -Javascript-npm,grunt,guip
- Continious Integration Tools-Jenkins,TravisCI,Bamboo
- Configuration Management Tools-puppet,Chef,Salt
- Visualization Tools-Container,Docker
- Monitoring Tools-APM(Application Performance Monitoring)
- Orchestration Tools-Kubernetes,Zookeeper

Answer (score -1):

I am glad to let you know that Alibaba Cloud had the specialized DevOps solution now.

https://www.alibabacloud.com/solutions/devops?spm=a2c5t.10695662.1996646101.searchclickresult.5b56710bYs5XVR